# Django Joins Query

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a `Ride` and `Vehicle` table where

```
class Ride(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, blank=True, null=True, unique=False)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to return a list of vehicles, where their ***LAST `ride.state` is NOT equal to `COMPLETED`***

Is there a way to do this via the ORM?

Comment: Have you figured out how to do this in SQL?

Comment: No but I have a list comprehension solution that is pretty terrible, O(n) size of the driver database

Answer (score 3):

```
 from django.db.models import Max, F
 Vehicle.objects.annotate(last_ride_id=Max("ride__id")).filter(ride_id=F("last_ride_id").exclude(ride__state="COMPLETE").distinct()
```

not tested but should work

Comment: I'm getting Max is not defined. When I changed to lowercase I get `ride__id` is not defined.

Comment: Sorry forgot to provide the import statement

Comment: Now I'm getting ride__id is not defined. BTW is there a site that explains all of this?

Comment: Fixed: yes there is django docs. Google making django queries and also google django aggregation